# Get r and s from ECDSA Signature as two concatenated integers (OpenSSL)

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, ecc

EVP_DigestSignFinal() gives me a DER encoded signature.

Some examples:

ECDSA-SHA-256

```
30 44 02 20 [..r..] 02 20 [..s..]
30 46 02 21 [..r..] 02 21 [..s..]
30 45 02 20 [..r..] 02 21 [..s..]
```

ECDSA-SHA-224

```
30 3d 02 1c [..r..] 02 1d [..s..]
30 3c 02 1c [..r..] 02 1c [..s..]
```

The size can vary and I want to concatenate them. What's a good way to know how many bytes the signature will be long?
Or is there a function in OpenSSL that's already implemented maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECDSA signature is encoded as an [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) structure, which is a `SEQUENCE` of two `INTEGER` values. When encoded, the first byte will by `0x30` (which means `SEQUENCE`), followed by the length, encoded over one or two bytes: if length is *n* bytes, then it will be encoded as a single byte of value *n* if *n* ≤ 127, or two bytes of value `0x81` then *n*, if 128 ≤ *n* ≤ 255 (the latter case may happen in case you use a "large" curve like P-521). These *n* bytes are the concatenation of the two `INTEGER` values, each with its own tag (a byte of value `0x02`), then its length (same encoding; in practice, over a single byte, since it would take a 1000-bit or so curve to need more than one), then the `INTEGER` value. The value of an `INTEGER` uses signed big-endian (so you may have a leading byte of value `0x00`).

Properly encoding and decoding ASN.1 structures is a difficult art. I don't know if OpenSSL has a public function for that. [This function](https://www.bearssl.org/gitweb/?p=BearSSL;a=blob;f=src/ec/ecdsa_atr.c;h=3a11226e49446667136e5825d9a171649f01aced;hb=57b217502046db74ea25bb84a1284e74e57bc8e8), from [another SSL library](https://www.bearssl.org/), converts from ASN.1 to "raw" ECDSA signatures ("raw" means: the two integer values are simply encoded in big-endian and concatenated, both being adjusted to have the same encoding length).